# Paste XML as Classes, can I put in metadata

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xsd.exe

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio.
I am using Paste Special
I am using Past XML as Classes.
The XML I have is XML another program generates.
I can force meta data into the XML.  (i.e. Say when a value of 123 is a string or a number)

Can I/How do I communicate this information to XSD or the IDE?

Comment: The only way to declare a type with xml is to have a schema.

Comment: I am looking for an example on how to feed this information to XSD or the IDE.